# Android emulator install pkcs12 certificate

Tags: android-emulator, certificate, vpn, pkcs#12

On the android emulator (android 4.x) it is not possible to install a pkcs12 (*.p12 /*.pfx) certificate. 
I can see the *.p12 file in "Settings->Security->Install from SD card" but the file is grayed out.

I want to use VPN via RSA/Ipsec and i have to install a client certificate.

On an "normal device" there are no problems.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

OK I habe the answer:
Just use Android 4.3 and it works. I don't know why all other versions > 4.3 doesn't work.